# Chrome on Android emulator x86

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-x86

I'm trying to install the Chrome browser on the Android emulator (x86 image) but can't seem to install it. Did anyone succeed in installing this on an emulator?

I tried by installing the Google Play Store, which failed, then I tried pushing a Chrome apk I found on the web with adb, but that crashed upon opening.

Any hints would be more than welcome!

Comment: Did you ever get Chromium working? I'm experiencing the same. It either crashes immediately upon opening or occasionally will throw a vague error message: "Unfortunately, Chromium Shell has stopped"

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem attempting to install Chromium APK onto an Android emulator. It would crash immediately upon trying to open the app. There is no guarantee that you are experiencing the same issue, but these steps helped:

1. Make sure your AVD has an SD card configured.
2. Use ARM processor instead of Intel Atom

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge number of other services that you need to do.  The simplest solution is to [install the Content Shell](http://paul.kinlan.me/installing-chrome-for-android-on-an-emulator/) which is the full renderer but not the browser ui (such as bookmarks, history etc)